# error excel dateadd error when result is zero

Tags: excel, vba, dateadd

I am using the following:

```
t_start_pre = DateAdd("n", -time_before, match_start(j))
```

So far it was working in many excel files.
Now I got a run time error, when the time_before is 60, and the match_start(j) is 1AM, so the result is expected to be zero.
I checked it with different time_before values, such as 59 - works well.

So the problem is with the zero value.

Please help: can I write this code better? should I check before executing the line for the input values?

Comment: For me this gives `00:00:00`: `DateAdd("n", -60, "1AM")`. Check in debugger what does `match_start(j)` hold.

Comment: What is the error? What line of code shows it?  Depending on how you have declared your variables, that line works perfectly OK in VBA.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thanks.  I don't know how I missed that 1!

Comment: Is the error on this specific line of code? If so, what is the error? If it ***isn't*** on this line of code, please edit the question to include more information about the error as well as the relevant code. I can't replicate this with the inputs you specify above.

Comment: The match_start(j) held 01:00:00. When I debugged it, I created a temp variable to include same input, to make sure the array has no effect. I can't recreate it at the moment, but the way I solved it is by adding a second to the match_start(j) to become 01:00:01 and there was no error any more. I know this is not a proper way to solve, but it works. I will be able to get back to this issue in 2-3 weeks from now.